# Please allow more websites to be added to my Careers profile

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, jobs

Since I have multiple websites targeting different audiences, I'd like to add more websites to my profile on the careers website.

Answer (score 3):

The `Personal statement` field supports [markdown syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) too - you could always just

- [make a](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149650/172936)
- [list of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149650/172936)
- [your websites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149650/172936)
- [there!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149650/172936)

Place your "main" website in the `Web site URL` field and have additional ones in the statement field. This is usually what people do in their Stack Overflow profiles. Take a look at [Jon Skeet's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) for an example. Just use normal markdown syntax as shown below -

> [image]

Comment: I'm not saying your suggestion is not valid. My answer is just a workaround :)

Comment: My edit was a bit tongue-in-cheek, but we in the Jon community have to look out for each other ;)

Comment: @jon - That mistake must get quite annoying :P I take it your name also lacks the usual "h"? :P

Comment: Hehe, you guessed it.

Comment: @Lix This question does seem to be about the Careers site though. Not SO/SE. The Careers site only contains a single box for a single URL.

Comment: @bar - Yes - but the idea of a markdown `ul` is available for the `Personal statement` field.

Comment: Fair enough, but you might want to update your answer to address this specifically. Especially with regards to the screenshot.

Comment: @bar - Agreed. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: My question was not so much a question, but indeed a feature request to allow more website to be added at the top of my profile. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

You can add the links to your websites under the "Apps and Software" section of your profile.  Enter the URL, and additional fields to tag the technologies used, describe the project, and detail your role will become available.